# E2E tests timeout when running against localhost

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, protractor

We have an application built with Angular 4 and webpack and we are experiencing strange timeouts/slowdowns when running end-to-end tests with Protractor against localhost.

If we run it against our deployed application on server all tests pass. If we run it against local build the tests are noticeably slower and randomly fail due to timeouts.

Just to mention that:

- speed of local and deployed application in browser is same
- version deployed on server is exactly the same build version as on local machine
- they use exactly same backend endpoint
- we tried webpack-dev-server, lite-server, http-server and superstatic and they all give same results
- delay set for elements is 5 sec
- page itself gets loaded immediately but content loads with random delays

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Firewalls, proxies, vpn?

Comment: Everything is in local network